# integration computation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Let $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)=1, \qquad 0<x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n<1$. I would like to evaluate the integral

$$\underset{\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n<1,\\ x_1>a,x_2>x_1+a,\cdots,x_n>x_{n-1}+a \end{array}\right\}}{\int  \int \cdots \int} f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)\,dx_n\, dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_1$$
for fixed $a$.

I wonder if you could check my answer and help me to correct it with explanation in the case that it is false.
$$\int_{a}^{1}  \int_{x_{1}+a}^{1} \cdots \int_{x_{n-2}+a}^{1} \int_{x_{n-1}+a}^1 f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)\,dx_n\, dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_1$$

Comment: Let $0 < a < 1/n$. The last formula is correct, but, unlike in the first formula, you can't replace $f$ with $1$: if $x_1$ is close to $1$, then $x_1 + a > 1$. The domain of integration in the first formula is
$$0 < x_1 - a < x_2 - 2 a < \cdots < x_n - n a < 1 - n a,$$
so the integral is equal to the volume of the simplex $0 < y_1 < y_2 < \cdots < y_n < 1 - n a$, which is $1/n!$ times the volume of an $n$-dimensional hypercube with edge length $1 - n a$. Then consider the cases $a < 0$ and $a > 1/n$.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you for your help, By your comment, The answer for $0 < a < 1/n$ is $\int_{a}^{1}  \int_{x_{1}+a}^{1} \cdots \int_{x_{n-2}+a}^{1} \int_{x_{n-1}+a}^1 n! \,dx_n\, dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_1$. Could you give me a clue for the case of $a>\frac{1}{n}$, how to obtain the limit integral Thanks.